# Google Maps + Currency Converter Special Characters Issue

Tags: google-maps, special-characters, currency

Info on Application: I have a currency converter application where the front-end is a Google Map with an info window opened up at the user's location.  There's a currency conversion form on the info window with two dropdown menus with a list of currencies that I get from an API.  I use Reverse Geocoding to get the name of the country or region from geolocation coordinates or from when the user clicks on a place.

The problem I have is with names of countries or regions with special characters in them.  I found that when I click on such a country or region, the app doesn't know what currency to pick in the dropdown which makes it just choose the first currency (AED).  Even when I use HTML escape sequences or copy-paste the name of the country (I'm printing the name of the country and the corresponding currency abbreviation to the console, so I try to copy-paste the name of the country printed to the console, which, since it's from Google Maps, is the one I need to use to avoid discrepancy issues; for the countries or regions whose names have special characters in them, like a letter with an accent mark on it or slash through it, what's printed in place of a currency abbreviation is the word `undefined`), I have the same issue occur.

I'm using a third-party CommonJS module for country-currency mapping, and that module has a `getCountryAbbreviation` function that I can pass the name of a country into in order to get the currency abbreviation for that country.  The name I pass into the aforementioned function has to match the name used in the module's source code or it won't work.  The module I'm using is https://github.com/payscale/country-currency-map.  This is my own JavaScript code: https://gist.github.com/DragonOsman/c6e8fb15343544e662f474c5a526d1c2.  I'm using Browserify to let the browser know about the module.

So does anyone have any idea how I can fix this?  If I need to clarify something or add more information, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the special character problem.

If there's anyone else who needs the info: What I did was keep country names in the module I'm using free of special characters and just replaced the special characters in the names returned from reverse geocoding with their "normal" versions.  And then it worked.

Here's the code:

```
let geo_coder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
geo_coder.geocode({ 'location': location }, function (geocode_results, status) {
    let currency_abbr;
    if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        if (geocode_results[1]) {
            let country = null;
            for (let r = 0, rl = geocode_results.length; r < rl; r++) {
                let result = geocode_results[r];
                if (!country && result.types[0] === "country") {
                    country = result.address_components[0].long_name;
                    console.log(country);
                    const fixed = result.address_components[0].long_name.normalize("NFKD").replace(/[^\x00-\x7f]/g, "");
                    result.address_components[0].long_name = fixed;
                    country = fixed;
                    currency_abbr = country_currency_map.getCurrencyAbbreviation(country);
                    console.log(currency_abbr);
                }
            }   
        }
    } else {
        form.innerHTML += "Geocoding not for the following reason: " + status;         
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < select2.options.length; i++) {
        select2.options[i].selected = select2.options[i].id === currency_abbr;
    }
});
```